# Shiny upload error lapply object not found

Tags: r, shiny

I've been struggling for 2 days to get a shiny app uploaded on shinyapp.io.  The app works fine in preview mode, but the error log keeps coming back with some version of the following at the end:

```
2018-10-20T18:39:10.922805+00:00 shinyapps[526123]: Warning: Error in lapply: object 'CountyData' not found
2018-10-20T18:39:10.938278+00:00 shinyapps[526123]:   70: listify
2018-10-20T18:39:10.938276+00:00 shinyapps[526123]:   71: lapply
```

Here's how i've tried to solve it so far, based on other things i've found online. Nothing has worked. My main object is called CountyData, and is tied to a csv called CountyData.csv

Attempt 1 - create a subfolder titled data, and add the csv to it.

```
data <- read.csv("./data/CountyData.csv") # added to very top of server script
```

Attempt 2 -

```
data <- read.csv("./data/CountyData.csv") # added to very top of both server and ui script
```

attempt 3 -

```
CountyData <- read.csv("./data/CountyData.csv") # added to very top of both server and ui script
```

attempt 4 - added to the top of both server and ui script (attempting to remove period as one person said that solved their issue

```
CountyData <- read.csv("/data/CountyData.csv")
```

attempt 5 - saved as an rdata, and tried

```
load("./data/object.rdata")
```

to both just top of server page, and top of server and ui page.

There are prob a few other minor variations on these things, but I cant get the csv file to upload and work with the server and ui code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jessica, after you read in `CountyData` as per Attempt 3, check to see if it actually loaded... I usually do `str(CountyData)` instead of just typing the data frame name so it doesn't scroll off the screen. Also, it would be helpful to post a full minimum reproducible example so we can cut and paste and get this working easily in our own R sessions. There are lots of places where code can diverge from our expectations. Thanks :) and good luck

Comment: That code works just fine on my rstudio, and my app works fine on preview, but that data doesn't read in when I try to publish my app. The data is uploading to shinyapp io, but my script can never find it for some reason (at least I think that's the issue) I'll upload the full code and data the next time I'm on my computer